# Configuring networked printer to archive print jobs

Tags: backup, printing

Our existing infrastructure has a shared printer running on a windows machine. 
It may be upgraded to a real network tcp/ip based printer in the near future.

How can I make it automatically keep a copy of whatever it is printing as a pdf?

Maybe use cups on a Linux machine, which will act as the print server, and create two print jobs: one to the pdf printer, the other to the network printer? Something like that?

Is there something easily available or a bunch of things I can glue together to make this work?